# Copy taskbar jump list to taskbar jumplist of a different program

Tags: microsoft-office, taskbar, jumplist

I have installed an updated MS Office version separately (to keep the old version, which is 32 bit). I would like to copy all my Jump list links from my old version to the new version.  Is there any way to do that?

Also, is there any way to copy the recent files between the apps?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround = open all the files from the old jumplist, drag link from saveas dialog to the new jumplist